# I want to create a function that will run when the screen width have increased or decreased

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code.

```js
function mymediafunction(media){
    if(media.matches){
        document.getElementById("log_in_container");
    logIn.style.display = "none";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("log_in_container");
    logIn.style.display = "block";      
    }
}
var media = window.matchmedia("(max-width:720px)");
mymediafunction(media);
media.addEventListener(mymediafunction);
```

I want the code to run if the user is greater than or less than 720px in width.

Comment: Hi @Pinnacle, welcome to SO and it's great you've put an example of what you're trying to do but this community isn't in the habit of writing your code for you, you may get some kind soul willing to do it but it'd be better if you tried to write it and then ask a question about a specific problem you're having.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use CSS media queries, which where designed exactly for that purpose?

Answer (score -1):

One method of doing this is to poll the width of the window/document every X milliseconds and fire your method if the new width is different than the last value. For example, using JQuery you can do something like this

```js
var lastWidth = $( document ).width();

setInterval(() => {
  var width = $( document ).width();
  if ( lastWidth != width ) {
    if ( lastWidth < 720 && width > 720 ) {
      // Call your function for width 720+
      widthOver720();
    } else if ( lastWidth > 720 && width < 720 ) {
      // Call your function for width under 720
      widthUnder720();
    }
    lastWidth = width;
  }
}, 500);
```